# How to compare rows with each other and keep only one row according to a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement as per below:

- IF More than 1 comment exist (group of name, lastname and door) and one of them includes NULL then keep only the record with the Null comment and discard the others.
- IF Null IS NOT one of them and the comment includes NOT AVAILABLE and REQUIRES. Keep Not available - discard REQUIRES
- IF all of them have only REQUIRES choose the record with the lowest amount or value.

```
    Name    Lastname   Comment                    Amount    Door
    John    R.         NULL                          250    1
    John    R.         NULL                          250    1
    John    R.         New design is available       250    1
    John    W.         Not available                 250    2
    John    W.         Requires additional comment   450    2
    John    S.         Requires further explanation  200    3
    John    S.         Requires more information     300    3
```

Result should come like below:

```
    Name    Lastname   Comment                    Amount    Door
    John    R.         NULL                          250    1
    John    W.         Not available                 250    2
    John    S.         Requires further explanation  200    3
```

I am trying to write a CTE to get the result but not sure how to compare the comment section something like below:

```
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT name,
           lastname,
           door,
           package,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY door ASC) AS RN
    FROM test)
SELECT distinct name,
           lastname,
           door,package,
       CASE when package IS NULL  THEN 'PASS' 
            when package like 'Not available%' then 'PASS' 
            when package like 'requires%' then 'PASS' else 'fail' END AS to_keep_or_not
     
FROM RNs
GROUP BY RN,
         name,
           lastname,
           door,package;
```

What would be the best approach to solve this kind of problem statement?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:

```
  with cte as (
select name ,lastname,comment,amount,door ,row_number()over(partition by name ,lastname order by comment ,(case when comment like '%Requires%' then amount else 0 end)) rn from testreq
where comment is null or comment like '%Not available%' or comment like '%Requires%')
select Name,lastname,comment,amount,door from cte where rn=1
order by door
```

**Output:**

```
|name|lastname|comment                     |amount|door|
|----|--------|----------------------------|------|----|
|John|R.      |NULL                        |250   |1   |    
|John|W.      |Not available               |250   |2   |
|John|S.      |Requires further explanation|200   |3   |
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ..requirement is to check  if there is "not available" present, then the other row should be discarded.so for below 
  John    W.         Not available                            250    2
  John    W.         Requires additional comment   450    2
only one row should come as a result 
 John    W.         Not available                            250    2

Comment: This query returns only one row for Jon W. and that's with 'Not available'. I have changed the order. Now answer is same as your desired output. Did I miss something? please let me know.

Comment: What I mean to say is that its not necessary that amount for "not available" is going to be less than the amount for "require",in that scenario this will not work.

Comment: Got it. Let me change my answer to appropriate one.

Comment: @Mini I have revised my answer. Amount only considered for comments with 'Requires'. Is there a chance for amount to be negetive?

Comment: @Mini If there is any other difficulties with this query please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You want an `order by` with a `case` expression . . . along with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, lastname
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN comment IS NULL THEN 1
                                               WHEN comment LIKE '%NOT AVAILABLE%' THEN 2
                                               ELSE 3
                                          END),
                                         amount
                                ORDER BY door ASC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM test t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```